# Settings up git workflow

Tags: git, svn, bitbucket

I am involved in project with three more developers and currently setting up the git repository in BitBucket. So far I have created the master repo and a develop branch. If I want to follow the git flow , how should I implement it? As in should I ask the other developers to checkout the developer branch and commit stuff straight to it or should they create their own branches based on the developer branch and create pull requests to when they need to commit something to developer branch ?

Comment: Doesn't matter; the nice thing about Git is that other developers can work however they want. All you need to do is wait for them to issue pull requests against your development branch.

Comment: So I should remove write access for them in the develop branch is it ? Since I want to review their work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding write access, either you install gitolite on your central repo server, or you manage **two repositories**:

- one for the developer to push to
- one for you to pull their work after review, trigger by merge request from the first one.

A classic intermediate repo would be a **[gerrit](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/)** one, which comes with its own review system.

---

I would recommend starting with  a **simple** workflow, based on [GitHub-Flow](http://scottchacon.com/2011/08/31/github-flow.html) at:
"**[A simple git branching model](https://gist.github.com/jbenet/ee6c9ac48068889b0912)**", with the main elements being:

> 1. `master` must always be deployable.
> 2. all changes made through feature branches (pull-request + merge)
> 3. rebase to avoid/resolve conflicts; merge in to `master`

[image: https://a248.e.akamai.net/camo.github.com/9783623eba280ba5ace8b9e63842be52af2f0546/687474703a2f2f7374617469632e62656e65742e61692f736b697463682f666c6f772d32303133303932362d3139333431392e706e67]

Then, when the release cycle becomes more complexe, you can have a look at [git-flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow).

Answer (score 1):

Where I work we have everybody use the git flow toolset. See https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/wiki/Installation for your OS. Anyway, once a developer have installed this and uses the commands provided there was much easier for us to get everybody on the same page. Especially since we use rebasing.